# Does pH affect physical property of agarose and poly(acrylamide) gel?

Tags: rheology, gel

We want to change pH in hydrogels of agarose and poly(acrylamide) by soaking into an acidic solution after gelation on pH 7.0.

Then, the physical property is changed? Now, we consider the condition of pH range from 7.0 to 4.0.

Please answer, and if you could, please inform the important reference.

Best, regards.

Comment: To understand the process, read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyacrylamide_gel_electrophoresis).